# PHP - Getting Current URL

Tags: php

This seems like a common questions but none of them seem to be what i'm looking for. If there is a website:

`www.example.com/test.php`

I want to pull the `test.php` and if it's something like:

`www.example.com/folder/folder1/test.php`

I want again to just pull `test.php` but everything seems to pull the exact path instead of just the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: why has this question "current url" in the subject when you're not asking for a url? also, if there's mod_rewrite forcing url www.exemple.com/test, which is rewritten to test.php, is it test.php or test that you want?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$query = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path = pathinfo( $query );
$what_you_want = $path['basename'];
```

Voila.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to set as answer! :)

Comment: shorter version: `$what_you_want = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Comment: It is important to know, that this returns the actual name of the file, not part of the URL. For details take a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475221/php-getting-current-url#comment25586710_6475257) under [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475257/548696). For the way to obtain part of the URL (not necessarily the name of the file), take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475257/548696).

Comment: -1 Because $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] doesn't return the URL.

Answer (score 41):

This will get you the name of the file that was requested (based on the URL invoked, not real location of the file - just in case you are using mod_rewrite):

```
$filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

For both `http://www.example.com/testing01.php` and `http://www.example.com/x/y/z/testing01.php` will give you:

```
testing01.php
```

Comment: it is about the same thing as the top answer but the top answer is broken down more for informational purposes IMO

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: I disagree. The basic difference is what we really show. You asked about "_Getting Current URL_". According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php): `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` obtains "_The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'._", while `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is equal to "_The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. (...)_", which may or may not be equal to the above. I explained the difference in my answer (in the part about `mod_rewrite`).

Comment: @Tadeck: correct, for the URL you must use the REQUEST_URI, this can result in executing a PHP script with a completely different name.

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = explode('/', $file);
$pfile = $break[count($break) - 1];
```

Comment: This comes back as "/folder1/folder2/test.php"

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Are you sure? `$pfile` should just hold `test.php`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee tested and it works for me:

http://localhost/test1/test2/file.php prints "file.php"