# loaded menu with jquery don't get activated

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm build some html with menu, and i'm inluding this with jquery on my pages. When users click on some link, the `a` element get some class: `ativado`.

My question is, how i can load the page who user click with the menu link "activated"?

I'm clear?

my menu:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">O Clube</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="sobre.html">- Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="basquete_em_franca.html">- Basquete em Franca</a></li>
            <li><a href="ginasio.html">- Ginásio</a></li>
            <li><a href="titulos.html">- Títulos</a></li>
            <li><a href="times.html">- Times</a></li>
            <li><a href="social.html">- Social</a></li>
            <li><a href="estatisticas.html">- Estatísticas</a></li>
            <li><a href="cronograma_historico.html">- Cronograma Histórico</a></li>
            <li><a href="pedroca.html">- Pedroca</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="hino.html">- Hino</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="equipe.html">A Equipe</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendario.html">Calendário</a></li>
    <li><a href="campeonatos.html">Campeonatos</a></li>
    <li><a href="socio_torcedor.html">Sócio Torcedor</a></li>
    <li><a href="noticias.html">Notícias</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="loja.html">Loja</a></li>
    <li><a href="parceiros.html">Parceiros</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="fale_conosco.html">Fale Conosco</a></li>
</ul>
```

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sf-menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.sf-menu a').removeClass('ativado');
            $(this).addClass('ativado');
            var novaURL = $(this).attr('href');
            $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);
        });

    });
</script>
```

css:

```
.sf-menu a.ativado{
    color:#FFF;
    background:#CC0000;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use ajax in this case.

Comment: but i need to change to another page, i can't load on the same page.. :(

Comment: I tested here and if I comment 3 first lines of "$('.sf-menu a').click(function(e) {" part, it works. So, the error must be in those 3 first lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to get the current page name:

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

*From: http://fuchangmiao.blogspot.com/2009/04/get-current-page-name-in-javascript.html*

You can then find the anchor tag which should be activated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sf-menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.sf-menu a').removeClass('ativado');
            $(this).addClass('ativado');
            var novaURL = $(this).attr('href');
            $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);
        });

        $(".sf-menu a[href='" + sPage + "']").addClass("ativado");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't tested it. You may need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: i can get the name, but is not applying the style to the link menu.

Comment: I forgot the quotes around the attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement some new technologies to achieve what you're trying to do. JavaScript is a client side language, so if you change the class by clicking on a DOM element, then that same click takes you to another page, you'll lose your class that was set by JS!

Here are just a few options that you could use. If you want me to elaborate on any of them, just leave a comment.

### Option 1: Server Side Scripting

The first option is handling these dynamic classes with a server side language, like PHP. For instance, [use a solution like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475221/php-getting-current-url) to get the URL of the current page. Then, write some logic like:

```
<a href="lala.php" class="<?php if($page=='lala') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
```

which will append the class if you're on that page. This is mostly what I do for websites that I'm just throwing together quickly.

### Option 2: AJAX

You could also make an ajax call to pull the data from a server and update the content on the page. This is bad because it won't update the URL or the user's browser history; it'll just look like they're browsing your page on the page itself.

### Option 3: AJAX + HTML5 Browser API

This option is the most sophisticated of them all, but it only works on modern browsers. What you'd do is make an AJAX call, and then use the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to modify the user's history. What this will do is make the new content appear, while also changing the URL in the browser window and adding the new page to the user's history -- all without a reload. Pretty amazing.

### Option 4: Linkable Tabs

This solution is pretty bad, I think, but it would do what you want. There are a plethora of possibilities; I won't reinvent the wheel by trying to list them all here. You can view some of them and see if any work for you.

[One](http://css-tricks.com/better-linkable-tabs/)
[Two](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/)
[Three](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/)

### Option 5: Hardcoded pages

Another option -- maybe the worst of them all -- would be putting the menu code on each of your webpages. Then on each page you could append the class to the proper link. I wouldn't do this, as it's too tedious to maintain if your website is more than a handful of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check those lines of your code:

```
e.preventDefault();
$('.sf-menu a').removeClass('ativado');
$(this).addClass('ativado');
```

I tested here commenting those lines and it worked. 
Maybe this e.preventDefault() is triggering an error and the rest of the code is not working properly.

Comment: this only prevents the default event of the item.. if i coment this lines.. the page changes, but the menu i have clicked it not "activated"