# Html/css/php selected navigation

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to this so I need your help, I have a navigation menu in my header. When a page is active, its tab has a special id named **menu_active**. I'm including this **header.php** in my pages to reduce redundancy.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">

            <?php 
                $pages = array( 'index.php' => 'Home', 'services.php' => 'Services', 'sitemap.php' => 'Calculators', 'about.php' => 'About'
                , 'contact.php' => 'Contact' );

                foreach( $pages as $url => $title ) {
                   $li = '<li ';
                   if( $url == 'index.php' ) {
                       $li .= 'class="alpha"';
                   } else if ( $url == 'contact.php' ){
                       $li .= 'class="omega"';
                   }

                   if( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] == $url ) {
                       $li .= 'id="menu_active"';
                   }
                   $li .= '><a href="' . $url . '"><span><span>' . $title . '</span></span></a></li>';
                   echo $li;
                }
            ?>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**UPDATE:**
**CSS**

```
      #menu {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:3px
    }
    #menu li {
float:left
    }
    #menu a {
display:block;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight:400;
color:#000;
background:url(../images/menu.gif) top repeat-x;
line-height:55px;
text-decoration:none;
  }
  #menu li span {
display:block;
background:url(../images/menu_left.gif) top left no-repeat
  }
  #menu .alpha span {
background:url(../images/left_menu.gif) top left no-repeat
  }
  #menu .alpha a:hover span, #menu .alpha#menu_active a span {
background:url(../images/left_menu_active.gif) top left no-repeat
  }
  #menu .omega span span {
background:url(../images/right_menu.gif) top right no-repeat
  }
  #menu .omega a:hover span span, #menu .omega#menu_active a span span {
background:url(../images/right_menu_active.gif) top right no-repeat
  }
  #menu li span span, #menu .alpha span span {
background:url(../images/menu_right.gif) top right no-repeat;
padding:0 60px
  }
  #menu a:hover, #menu #menu_active a {
color:#fff;
background:url(../images/menu_active.gif) top repeat-x
  }
  #menu a:hover span, #menu #menu_active a span {
background:url(../images/menu_left_active.gif) top left no-repeat
  }
  #menu a:hover span span, #menu #menu_active a span span, #menu .alpha#menu_active a span span, #menu .alpha a:hover span span {
background:url(../images/menu_right_active.gif) top right no-repeat
  }
```

I can get to work the first and last menu, but the active states still to no avail. What seems to be the problem in here? And can you help what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: can you show us your code of css ? showing html also, wouldn't be bad, maybe you've got problems there too

Comment: @aspirinemaga I've added my css, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; is enough to check the url?

I think you have to use this:

```
$query = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path = pathinfo( $query );
$what_you_want = $path['basename'];
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475221/php-getting-current-url)

And don't use "==" to compare, use "===" better.

I think you have to check empty space between class and id too. Take a look into Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to check what HTML code is produced?

Comment: id="menu_active" is not included in the current page. I checked the source code.

Comment: Hey when I tried adding the above code, it now works! Thanks a bunch buddy!

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck :)
Btw. if you have such issues, just try to print out the variables and check their value, e.g. in HTML. The fastest way to find the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` contains not only the name of the PHP file being executed but also its path relative to the document root (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Use the **basename** function to extract the file name from **PHP_SELF**:

```
if(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == $url)
{
    $li .= 'id="menu_active"';
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php for more details.

Comment: Does it appear in the source code? Then it's a client-side problem. Otherwise it's a problem with your PHP code. What's the exact value for `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`? And `basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])`? Which page are you testing your code on that should have the *menu_active* class?

Comment: I'm testing my index.php, it is the current page, yet no change at all. When I viewed the source code, id='menu_active' wasn't included.

Answer (score 0):

If its what I think you mean, I just had the same question. I was able to get it resolved.

[CSS navigation with PHP include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935192/css-navigation-with-php-include/20935339?noredirect=1#20935339)